# javascript how drag over event cancel with ESC key

Tags: javascript, events

My javascript script, I need solution in javascript native (not jquery)

```
var dropZone = document.getElementById('Library');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#PanelUpload").slideDown();
});
```

How do I implement the code to cancel the event "dragover" with ESC Key?

Note: my english is poor.

Comment: Aside from the `$("#PanelUpload")` part of the code (which appears to be completely unrelated to canceling the event), this appears to do exactly what you want it to with no help from jquery or another library.

Comment: You can't cancel the event you can only modify what happens in it (dragover). What you can do instead is detect whether esc has been pressed then if the panel is not in its initial position then set it back otherwise do nothing and if ESC has not been pressed then slide the panel down.

Comment: What a **bad** luck

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if(e.key == "Escape"){ // key press ESC detect
        $("#PanelUpload").slideUp();
    }
});
```

It really is not a solution, is an option, but it works.